# Ubuntu 17.10 takes too long to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 17.10

I bought a Samsung EVO 850 SSD (256 GB) 5 months ago, and I have been struggling a lot with boot times.

My computer:

- Asus ROG GL752VW
- CPU: Intel Core i7-6700HQ
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M
- RAM: 16GB DDR4
- Storage: 256 GB SSD / 1 TB HDD

I did a fresh dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10. I first installed Windows 10 (200 GB SSD) without any problems. I tried to enter Windows 10 and I just had to wait 4 seconds to start configuring the system. Then, I booted into Ubuntu Live and I installed Ubuntu 17.10 alongside Windows 10.

I always have problems with my Nvidia on Ubuntu trying to shutdown or reboot, so I edited /etc/default/grub and changed:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
to
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

After this, I installed Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-387
```

The problem is, when I get into GRUB I choose Ubuntu, and then there is a purple screen that lasts 15 seconds or so. I'm gonna paste some outputs of commands to see if you find out what happens. Thank you guys.

*sudo blkid*

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Reservado para el sistema" UUID="3AC6D708C6D6C2F5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="70b3f7e5-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="8442F4DB42F4D2C2" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="70b3f7e5-02"
/dev/sda5: UUID="a8e9ad9b-c36b-4b8b-a524-23ea53630ebb" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="70b3f7e5-05"
/dev/sdb1: PARTUUID="70b3f7da-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Linux" UUID="51c1a197-5367-42ad-871e-fa7ae527fa7a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="70b3f7da-02"
```

*cat /etc/fstab*

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a8e9ad9b-c36b-4b8b-a524-23ea53630ebb /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

*cat /etc/crypttab*

```
cat: /etc/crypttab: No such file or directory
```

*free -h*

```
                total       used        free       shared     buff/cache  available
Memoria:         15G        1,6G         12G         97M        995M         13G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

*sudo swapon -s*

```
(no output in terminal - blank screen)
```

*gparted*

[Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTj1V.png)

[Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYyeU.png)

*sudo journalctl --list-boots*

```
0 fc1161642ffc4b10af28b41ce4bcef84 Fri 2017-12-01 21:29:55 CET—Fri 2017-12-01 2
```

*sudo journalctl -b -1*

```
Specifying boot ID or boot offset has no effect, no persistent journal was found.
```

*sudo journalctl -b -0*

[Output was too large for the post -> pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FBihQ2XR)

*ls -al /*

```
total 2097268
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root       4096 dic  1 19:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root       4096 dic  1 19:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 dic  1 19:24 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 dic  1 19:33 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 dic  1 19:19 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root       4500 dic  1 21:29 dev
drwxr-xr-x 127 root root      12288 dic  1 22:20 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 dic  1 19:19 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         33 dic  1 19:25 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-17-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         33 dic  1 19:20 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root       4096 dic  1 19:32 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 dic  1 19:32 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 oct 18 20:32 lib64
drwx------   2 root root      16384 dic  1 19:17 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 dic  1 20:23 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 oct 18 20:32 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 oct 18 20:32 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 290 root root          0 dic  1 21:29 proc
drwx------   5 root root       4096 dic  1 20:25 root
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root        800 dic  1 22:17 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      12288 dic  1 19:32 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 oct 13 23:25 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 oct 18 20:32 srv
-rw-------   1 root root 2147483648 dic  1 19:17 swapfile
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 dic  1 21:29 sys
drwxrwxrwt  13 root root       4096 dic  1 22:25 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root       4096 dic  1 19:55 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root       4096 oct 18 20:42 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         30 dic  1 19:25 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-17-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         30 dic  1 19:20 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic
```

*systemd-analyze blame*

```
7.206s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 3.433s fwupd.service
  701ms dev-sda5.device
  427ms udisks2.service
  367ms ModemManager.service
  366ms accounts-daemon.service
  323ms systemd-logind.service
  322ms grub-common.service
  311ms apport.service
  308ms thermald.service
  298ms gpu-manager.service
  290ms rsyslog.service
  278ms pppd-dns.service
  136ms apparmor.service
  135ms systemd-resolved.service
```

Comment: You have a problem with your /swapfile. Did you create it manually, or was it created during a 17.10 fresh install?